# CDMA cell data interruption on iPhone. NSError code?

Tags: iphone, ios, nserror, cdma

I have a scenario where a NSURLConnection is in progress.

As we all know, CDMA phones (think Verizon, Sprint) can't handle data and phone calls at the same time. Does anyone know what, if any, NSError is returned when the connection is interrupted by a phone call?

Is there any error handling?  Does didFailWithError get called or does it automatically go into the background?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question. While I do not know the answer to this case specifically but if you implement this NSURLConnection function:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

And run your code on a device debugging with xcode, you should be able to see for yourself.

edit:

Adding to the other answer, I found the list of all URL errors, so hopefully you can narrow down which one you're looking for.
[errors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html)

**pre-submission edit:
I found it! The error is:
NSURLErrorCallIsActive**

> Returned when a connection is attempted while a phone call is active on a network that does not support simultaneous phone and data communication (EDGE or GPRS).

Comment: I would but neither I nor anyone on my team has a AT&T / Sprint phone to test against. Thus the hive mind.

Comment: I assume you meant Verizon / Sprint, also see my edit. Good luck!

Comment: Okay…

The error that is received still has a code of 0 but the underlying error has the code of -1019 which is NSURLErrorCallIsActive!  

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

//connection:didFailWithError:error

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 //handle error here
    if([error code] == NSURLErrorCallIsActive)//error code for NSURLErrorCallIsActive = -1019
    {
        //if we can identify the error
    }else{
        //otherwise handle the error generally
    }
}
```

Comment: check my answer update for the correct error for this particular scenario.